Does anyone know how to solve/bypass the invisible reCaptcha badge using selenium button click?
Here is the website I am trying to solve - I can populate the data but when I click submit it closes the browser:
https://www.planenoise.com/panynj/daPRAbr9/qs114wbt.php
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from pypasser import reCaptchaV2, reCaptchaV3
from capmonster_python import RecaptchaV2Task, RecaptchaV3Task

API_KEY = "AIzaSyB6om4qXEGnsjb2EUkhzZ1FsE09JU0D-WM"
DATA_SITEKEY = "6LeVD70ZAAAAAKTfVkAMc1dLdhsVtSilkr265_vZ"

captcha_response_value = "03AFcWeA7..."

def solve_recaptcha(driver):

    code = "03AFcWeA7xqiUs9KYXdEfUdGT8qFa3L7YN7EeianbmzoQ5d-1T2qTpzk3sg8vm9Jc5Ht9evXAdLLr1zYeHJOR48mDwqjGRaJcj70yXjlNbQeT2XF_ca0dZVSZy2aXSabhj7olCh2TIOxHQOMfKprExdMBfsD5QiPNO1X7byQDJx0CQew2PljbVrvamqzyRLFEvKrH0WqOR9QaDce_SLQjdXk-GeegVAcUpdEfE0Nu3jQDQ9s_JUqJKPBbR0VmVSk_6LZWRrk4Kwq8qPVW2QRsytg1pakw4jHZYPbOInQk2v-glrzBDWoCQK79FL9sMraS3_s1V0ZyHpv4EXmyZGDDXNC08PJB7nWzC1AXmTcx6ied52A_NDMjdsybg59N9IMP9JrRvcs_-qytH6QnXYK48ewVjUdr3wnkTC81dzjooryKERh8B_3esf2ldlGGiLzkB-Shk2JUlmevDIbcRL2bw9x2y_dXeV7Nlhfz0qR5_yWrPzsPu9ck45F8fJexHGhfPVQVmPifgCh04UFI_PzXtrzk14AhP7tWVSoBKJsEdi-eP3chPR-DM-dce3-yHvsjzRgSuv9pgdfGLFfrfDrhPDV4o_bcKqLJGVomuUdWsOzZvk6vKgn2pKVKHk088AZ9fKDkJSzt1d9ogG9spifZ15qYoRFpfZcYm_neK3ev4YVP4nyyPozvxDy9gbX_VCGB7pn7JzSSPEaacOZ-QD_EWnyhg1mcyAi_HuWeqkuQPoM3IklM_gTKgvQPWhBZp-R6sVksWWvAuDNhaqqQ19MwCy6JSQn3ngoqo9Nrs5uRfsZTJRKbDOO8hJ7TO6wQfVGNekHs8HZtoAY1dRvUuZhW_mM3sYXbIxMixgJepf_TEpC4O_HXd94iGlNc"
    # Set the solved Captcha
    recaptcha_response_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'g-recaptcha-response')
    driver.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{code}";', recaptcha_response_element)

when I use any of the above solver it complains about site key errors.

it closes the browser -- what? Websites can't do that.  You must have made some other mistake.  Show us the selenium code.

The whole point of a captcha is to prevent you from performing automated actions on a site.  If it was easy to get around it wouldn't be doing its job.

It's using hidden reCaptcha V2 along with reCaptcha3

@John Gordon, actually websites can do that by forcing the browser to crash.  (not a very friendly thing to do though... I've seen it happen when using devTools)  As for the question, it won't be easy to bypass even if you send a true "isTrusted" user event.
